# Fixing timeframe in pinecode strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am new to pine code and i want to draw lines (horizontal) on second 5 min candle high and low, however i want to fix this timeframe in strategy.
Currently in below code, if i view the chart in 3 min, strategy changes to 3 min high low.. I want it to be fixed for 5 min irrespective of whatever is being viewed. Can someone help?

//@version=5

```
indicator("opentime",  shorttitle="OPENTIME", overlay=true)

import PineCoders/VisibleChart/3 as ch

var lines = array.new_line()
var labels = array.new_label()
var barnum = 0
var _low = low
var _high = high

if session.isfirstbar
barnum := bar_index
if barstate.isconfirmed and bar_index == barnum + 1
_low := low
_high := high

if barstate.isconfirmed and bar_index == barnum + 1
_low := math.min(low, _low)
_high := math.max(high, _high)

rightmost_bar = ch.rightBarIndex()

// clear labels
for lb in labels
label.delete(lb)

// clear lines
for ln in lines
line.delete(ln)

array.clear(lines)
array.clear(labels)

array.push(lines, line.new(bar_index - 1, _low, bar_index, _low, style=line.style_solid,          extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#8f9197, 1), width=1))
array.push(labels, label.new(rightmost_bar - 1, _low, text="Low: " + str.tostring(_low), color=color.new(#F5F5EC,1), style=label.style_label_upper_right, textalign=text.align_right))

array.push(lines, line.new(bar_index - 1, _high, bar_index, _high, style=line.style_solid, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#8f9197, 1), width=1))
array.push(labels, label.new(rightmost_bar - 1, _high, text="High: " + str.tostring(_high), color=color.new(#F5F5EC,1), style=label.style_label_upper_right, textalign=text.align_right))
```

I tried changing it by keeping a variable but not sure to implement. Tried ChatGPT but not getting right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html?highlight=security_lower_tf#request-security) or [security_lower_tf()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html?highlight=security_lower_tf#request-security-lower-tf) functions to request data from other timeframes.

Below examples fetches `high` and `low` values:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Symbol/TF")
symbolInput = input.symbol("", "Symbol & timeframe", inline = "1")
tfInput = input.timeframe("", "", inline = "1")

[hi, lo] = request.security(symbolInput, tfInput, [high, low])

plot(hi, "hi", color.lime, 3)
plot(lo, "lo", color.fuchsia, 3)
```

Comment: The above code isnt giving me high low of only Second candle. It keeps changing the levels as candles appears for further in day

Comment: It was just an example. If you need data from lower timeframes, you should use the `request.security_lower_tf()` function.